# SCP copying error : Not a directory

Tags: file, directory, scp, copying, renaming

I want to copy a file from my local system to a remote host. I want to specify the file name while copying.

This is my command for copying.

```
scp config/1 root@remote:/home/user/config/2
```

I want to rename the file while copying or with the same name like this.

```
scp config/1 root@remote:/home/user/config/1
```

But I dont want to use like the below command.

```
scp config/1 root@remote:/home/user/config/
```

When I specify the filename i get the error: Not a directory

Comment: what is your file name... 1?

Comment: yes . 1 is my file name

Comment: if destination file exists, maybe scp assumes it's a directory, tries to copy in `1/1` then fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known [bug in openssh](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1768), unfortunately not fixed, even though there is a patch for that.

In short, it means that the file does not exists, but the `scp` is confused by the trailing slash.

Comment: Now It is fixed :)

Comment: I'm still getting this as well 

Comment: @Mikeumus still not fixed.

Comment: @Jakuje, a peer helped figured it out. Try to go to the local folder and `scp *.js user@example.com:/folder/`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the scp command from the local machine, not on the remote. You don't need the ssh at all:

```
user@local $ scp -P 2222 file.ext username@domain:~/
```

Comment: The `username@domain` part uses SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I got error "Not a directory" when tried scp with "-p" instead of "-P" for remote port number.
Check your syntaxis.